# Why would an Email sent from a journey get stuck in the triggered send queue with no error?

Tags: marketing-cloud, journeybuilder, queue, triggered-send

I built a basic journey with a Sales Cloud entry event which sends out an email once the field in Sales Cloud is updated to a specific value.

If I make the change in Sales Cloud on the object, the contact and all subsequest data requested from the journey's entry event are placed in the journey's data extension and then the contact is placed in the journey.

They hit the Send Email event and the email triggers as expected but it never sends.

I go into Interactions>Triggered Sends>Journey Builder sends and I see the email is hung in queue.

I've paused and restarted the trigger several times with no luck.
I've done a send preview of the email template to the Journey DE to see if there is an error but the email renders as expected and passes validation too so I have no indication of error.

I checked the sender profile but I see nothing there that might stop it from going through either.

Does anyone have any other suggestions of what might be wrong? Why wont this email go out?

Answer (score 5):

So as I posted this question, an email came through from Salesforce support thanks to auto case opening we have when any of our triggered sends are paused due to an error and the error gave me the information I needed.

In case anyone else comes across this thread and has this problem, the issue occurred becase we implemented a feature to auto-append utm tagging to emails for google analytic tracking.
We set it up such that if the utm tagging areas are left blank in the email's properties pane that the utm_campaign would default to the email's name and the utm_source would default to the email's sendable data extension.

When sending from a Sales Cloud sourced journey Data Extension, the DE name is VERY long and cumbersome- when this defaulted, it caused a character count error and the email could not send.

This did not show up in the Send Preview becase the auto append utm tagging feature we implemented does not actually 'work' until the email is actually sent.

Comment: Thanks for sharing Julie! Have you had any issues with the auto-append? I've seen cases where e.g. deep linking to an app doesn't work because the app store or google play links crashes when they are wrapped with the google analytics parameters.